# Unable to log into Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1.
Last time I did nothing especial, but suddenly some problem appear:
I have a login screen (using lightdm), when I attempt a login, I get a console session and returned to the login screen. I have same problem if I try "Guest session".
I see that it is a known issue, so I tried everything from following steps:
I succeed to to login with my account in console mode (ctrl+alt+f1)
I checked, and I don't have problem with disk space
I removed .XAuthority
I configured to use gdm
I reinstalled lightdm
I included my user to nopasswdlogin group
But nothing help...

So, these are errors from /var/log/auth.log in this step:

```
Oct  3 01:11:48 alphabet-2 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Oct  3 01:11:48 alphabet-2 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Oct  3 01:11:48 alphabet-2 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "andrey"
Oct  3 01:11:48 alphabet-2 dbus[704]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.35" (uid=104 pid=1709 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=1169 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
```

After I reconfigure lightdm new .Xauthority file appear with root as owner, I put my user as owner and gave 777 permissions. The result is: when I try login, lightdm hangs on login process, it just stop and don't do nothing, I even can't press on screen buttons or change password, it just hangs up.

GDM also hangs up.

And these are errors after I get permissions for .Xauthority:

```
Oct  3 01:11:48 alphabet-2 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Oct  3 01:11:48 alphabet-2 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Oct  3 01:11:48 alphabet-2 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "andrey"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, so I reinstalled gnome, unity, lightdm and gdm and now succeed to login to "Ubuntu" session in gdm, but still have same problem in login to "User defined session": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709143/what-it-mean-user-difined-session-in-window-manager 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check that the file `.Xauthority`, is owned by your user, not root. You can change it by doing the following when logged in as root in your users home directory:

```
chown andrey .Xauthority
```

Comment: I remove this file and then my login works.

Answer (score 1):

The key message is:

> requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "andrey"

It seems that your system recently downloaded updates that affected the `PAM` system. So, if you log in as root and create a password for user andrey using the following command:

```
passwd andrey
```

then most likely you will be able to login.

Comment: I success to login with my user to console.

Comment: good, what about X?

Comment: Yesterday I succeed to login to "Recovery console" using lightdm screen (you have there 2 options for each user: "User defined session" and "Recouvery console") and opened firefox from there, but today I don't succeed even this, I have same symptoms. I don't cnow other way for login to X.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

```
apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Then use gnome classic (with or without effects).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Serge, but in case that's not the issue, check the amount of free space on the drive.  You get the same issue if `/home` is maxed out.

Comment: No, I don't have problems with disk space...